Six Group Markov Chain
I would like to model the population migrations of a social network comprised of 6 interacting groups each of which can be influenced by each other and 2 external forces. Each of the 6 groups have a discrete probability density function that influences its behavior in gaining or losing members consistent with the population of the network remaining static. That is, a “conservation of population” is ensured; members of one group may migrate to another but the population of the network remains constant.
Can Mathematica model something as complex as this using a Markov chain?  If so, is there an online video or other intro material available to help someone learn to do this in Mathematica?
Any help appreciated.

Sure... no problem at all.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XURddoVvpTc
